# Why toString(2) is going to n % 2 and return the divisor remainder?

Tags: javascript

In this case when n is a number parameter in the function.
Why is `toString(2)` going to `n % 2` and return the divisor remainder?
I thought that toString just return a number into a string.

```
+n.toString(2)
```

```js
function toBinary(n) {

  var toBinary2 = +n.toString(2)

  return toBinary2

}
console.log(toBinary(2))
```

Comment: what value has `n`?

Comment: Please provide an example value of `n`, your expected result, and the actual result.

Comment: n was 2 and the result was 10

Comment: If you provide an argument to [*Number.prototype.toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-number.prototype.tostring), it's used as the radix (i.e. base). The default is 10, but you can use any integer from 2 to 36, so what you're getting is n base 2.

Comment: @EdgarChe Ok, and what result were you expecting? 10 isn't the remainder of 2 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `Number#toString` is a *base*.

Calling `.toString(2)` on a number will return that number in *binary*.

`2` in binary is `10`, so that is why `(2).toString(2)` returns `10`.

Comment: haa ok, so If I put a parameter into toString(2) is going to return the binary number. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> Why is toString(2) going to n % 2 and return the divisor remainder?

[toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) takes **radix** as parameter and `toString(2)` **converts the number into binary equivalent string**.

`+Number(2).toString(2)` converts the binary equivalent to the number again, **but doesn't do binary to decimal conversion**.

So, `+Number(2).toString(2)` => `+"10"` => `10`